# Do While - Overflow error

Tags: vba

This code looks for the column with header "Quantity Dispensed," then convert the strings in the column by treating the right three digits as decimals, e.i. `00009102" = 9.102`

```
Sub ConvertDec()
Dim colNum As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer

colNum = WorksheetFunction.Match("Quantity Dispensed", ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("1:1"), 0)
i = 2

Do While ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, colNum).Value <> ""
    x = Evaluate(Cells(i, colNum).Value)
    Cells(i, colNum) = Int(x / 1000) + (x Mod 1000) / 1000
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

I'm getting Overflow error on the line "x = Evaluate..." while executing.

The values in the column are in string form. e.g. `"0000120000"`.

Comment: try to change `Dim x As Integer` to `Dim x As Long`. max value of integer is only 32768. Also it'd be more reliable to use `Dim i As Long`. Btw, is there any reason to use `x = Evaluate(Cells(i, colNum).Value)` instead `x = Cells(i, colNum).Value`?

Comment: The values in the column are in string form e.g. "0000120000"

Comment: `120000` greater than max value of integer `32768`. Use `Long` type instead. And there is no need to use `Evaluate`

Comment: That seemed to be the problem. I read that Integer holds up to 2,147,483,647, but the max value you mentioned is clearly correct.

Comment: it's in VB.NET max value of integer 2147483647, in VBA - 32768

Comment: Thanks Simico for the help.

Comment: To be more versatile on future data, use **Double** for calculation variables, say `Dim x As Double: x = CDbl(Cells(i, colNum).Value)`, and then `Cells(i, colNum).Value = Round(x/1000, 3)`. You can also change the loop to `Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, colNum))`.

Answer (score 1):

> 120000 is greater than the maximum value of integer 32768. Use the Long type instead.

[*Simoco*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795882/do-while-overflow-error#comment34760530_22795882)